# was hacked or were hacked

Tags: word-choice

I were wondering if in the sentence

> Sorry, I [was\were] hacked

i should use was or were. I know, that according to the book, you should use "was", due to it being singular. Yet on the other hand i've stumbled upon an article on bbc.com, where it was stated that "were" might be used, in formal cases. For instance if you are to inform your superiors, or whatsoever.

Could someone clarify that?

Comment: When something really has happened, you have to use "was" - "I **was** hacked". When talking about conditions or uncertainty or desire, you should use "were", although "was" is becoming more and more acceptable - "I **wish** I **were** hacked", "**If** I **were** hacked, I would cry."

Comment: I wouldn't trust the BBC's opinions on use of English these days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use "was", in "I was hacked".

Us Brits often use the collective plural and singular interchangeably when discussing things like groups and organisations such as:

> The team were fairly beaten / The team was fairly beaten.

Without knowing the sentence in which you saw the "were hacked" similarity, I can only speculate as to it being either a plural article or the usage I describe above.

Comment: i were just considering the sentence "i * hacked". THe thing is that I've seen that it's sometimes used in form of "i were hacked", not in case of speculating over anything (i mean 2nd clause, i guess)

ANd that's why i were wondering about it. You know, passive, and things.

(although i know that i would never say "he were hacked")

Comment: If it's those three words alone, it is always "I was hacked". "I were hacked" is never correct, with the exception of local dialects - but we'll forget about that for now!

Answer (score 0):

**I was hacked**

You might me misunderstanding **"If I were hacked"** with **"I was hacked"**
https://www.englishforums.com/English/IWishIWasWereThere/bzvrw/post.htm

You don't say, "I are hacked." right?

> Verb 'To be' in Past Simple with I is "was".